# How can I send cursor's values to an string array[]

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-arrayadapter

As I say at the title, I want to save my cursor's values to an string array. I will use this array in a ArrayAdapter and call setLineAdapter(ArrayAdapter).. I have these codes but LogCat says at **arr[i] = crr.getString(i)** line have a problem... Can somebody help me?

```
DBAdapter db;
String arr[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

    ArrayAdapter<String> AA = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);

    try {
          Cursor crr = db.getRecord(4);

          crr.moveToFirst();

          for (int i = 0; i <= cr.getCount(); i++){ 
            arr[i] = cr.getString(i);
            crr.moveToNext();
    }}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    setListAdapter(AA);
    db.close();
```

Comment: Maybe like 

    String arr[]=new String[cr.getCount()];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as using do-while and use `ArrayList` instead of Array populating dynamic values from cursor :

```
 ArrayList<String> arrcurval=new ArrayList<String>();
if (crr.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
       arrcurval.add(crr.getString(0)); //<< pass column index here instead of i

     } while (crr.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Thanx... Everything is OK now =)

Comment: Now, how can I do a onListItemListener, which opens a TableView, when I clicked the items? I cannot do it with **if position is x, start intent** I suppose... Because I dont know how many items will be there... Listener should open the TableView and also should send a integer(index) to TableView to say which item has chosen. And TableView should get the data from DataBase, and show it; using the index which is sent by Listener? But, I have no idea how can I do it... (or am I wrong?)

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar : to get current task done you will need to set `setOnItemClickListener` for ListView and do your work. try it if you have any issue then make a new question for new issue .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate the array, thus:

```
      Cursor crr = db.getRecord(4);
      int n = crr.count();
      arr = new int[n];
```

Comment: You may also want to replace `cr.getString(i)` to get the String from the proper column, `cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(THE_INDEX))` :)